# how to save the time that i send data to database inside it?

Tags: php, mysql, time

Good day every one!

In general, my question is about time function in php/mysql, how i can save time in mysql database? for date I chosed "date type" in the database to save $date and i wrote this code in php:

`$date=date("y-m-d");`

and this is my whole code about that part:

```
<?php 
include_once ("connection.php");
$name=$_POST['sent_by'];
$id=$_POST['hidden_id'];
$id2=$_POST['hidden_id2'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$submit= $_POST['submit'];
$date=date("y-m-d");
$time=time('yyyy-mm-d hh:mm:ss');


if($submit){

$place="INSERT INTO comments VALUES('','$name','$message','$id','$id2','$date','$time')";
$run = mysql_query("$place");
die("Your message have been sent Successfully !! <a href='member.php'>click here to return to your page</a>");
}



?>
```

**for time what function i have to use? and which type i have to choose in database?**

please help me!

thanks and regards

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you're passing unfiltered, unvalidated user input ($_POST) directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is that you use either a timestamp or datetime type rather than the date type since you want both the date and time component.  A timestamp type has some special properties you need to be aware of, but if you have the option to utilize a timestamp then that's preferable from a storage standpoint.  See [this](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/93-Too-much-information-about-the-MySQL-TIMESTAMP.html) for more information.

You also should simply let the database set the time when inserted, which can be done automatically with a timestamp or manually using NOW().

One way of doing this, based on your code would be to change your query to be:

```
$place="INSERT INTO comments VALUES('','$name','$message','$id','$id2', NOW())";
```

Notice that you no longer want or need php to create a date variable.  The value of your DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column will be set to the system time of the mysql database server.

Comment: can u plz tell me what i have to write in php if i choose timestamp type in database? i tried this `$time=now();` and i chose time type in database but an error howed for me says "Call to undefined function now() "